# Highcharts tickinterval set to one minute shows only one date

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts graph of speed(y axis) and time( x axis), each second posts a new speed, which means in an hour I will have 3600 data point, and that is a lot. I found out about `tickInterval` and the ability to shorten the amount of time drawn on the x axes, but as soon as I set it the ticks labels disappear and it shows only the first minute label

Here are two graph comparison of how it look like with `tickInterval` and without

**without `tickInterval`**:

[image]

**With `tickInterval`:**

I would have expected to see a tick label on x axis every minute but instead I see only this ? hmm ?

[image]

here is my code with less data points than I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyc89zop/1/

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: In this case your `tickinterval` is the jump between data points. Try it with 1 and then 2 and it will help you understand what I mean

Comment: @musefan any idea why is that ? there documentation clearly says for time you use `tickInterval` and scale it in milliseconds

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit off with my highcharts at the min. I expect it will be a certain property you have overlooked that means it gets treated differently

Comment: I saw your fiddle, you are missing a couple of things. There is no such type as `time`, it should be `datetime`. If the xAxis type is `datetime` then the supplied x values should be in milliseconds. And when xAxis is `datetime`, then you don't set x values as categories. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyc89zop/2/) is an example of how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things:

**1)** You have specified your axis `type` as "Time" which is not a valid option. What you want is `datetime`.

**2)** You have then specified `categories` for the x axis. `categories` and `datetime` axis types are mutually exclusive - you must use only one or the other, not both.

To get the proper dates with a `datetime` axis type, you specify either

**1)** an x value for each data point,in millisecond epoch time, or

**2)** a `pointStart` and `pointInterval` property for the series

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointStart
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointInterval

Comment: ok so that is understandable, but those 2 options for removing categories won't solve my problem because it is not always every second or millisecond, it is random timestamps array, that I need to feed it into the x axis, if I can't use categories for date time, what other way can I do that ? that array in my JSfiddle is a shorten example of what I usually feed the graph at x axis

Comment: So you should be able to use tickPositoner and manually set positions on your xAxis to x values of your points. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cyc89zop/3/

Comment: @MohamadZein That's what my option "**1**"  above is for: you supply the data as `[x,y]` pairs, and the axis builds according to the datetime information contained in the data array. This is the standard way of populating datetime data in Highcharts.

Comment: @jlbriggs okay here is what I want to do, but now the numbers on the xaxis are wrong http://jsfiddle.net/cyc89zop/5/

Comment: Still 2 things **1)** `type: "Time"` should be `type: "datetime"`; **2)** The dates that you send as the `x` value must be epoch format, in milliseconds ( *reference: http://www.epochconverter.com/* ) - integer values, rather than formatted strings.